# i want to convert date Data to date?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I get data from open weather api and when i convert it i got the full date i want to extract only the hours :

> sunrise: 1607412091
> i try this method

```
var daterise= data.sys.sunrise;
var exactdate= new Date(daterise*1000);
document.getElementById("rise").innerHTML="Sunrise:"+ exactdate;
```

and i got the full date

> Tue Dec 08 2020 08:21:31 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)

I want just the hour
i want to extract the hours from the date ??

Comment: [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Comment: @David tthank you it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cosnt hours = exactdate.getHours()
```

Comment: ok thank you it works

Comment: Glad to help, Please mark as correct answer :)